# Effective group permission of a directory - setgid ineffective

Tags: linux, permissions, acl

I have this `/srv` directory that, for convenience, I would like members of the `wheel` group to have write access to, and for any files and directories created to transitively inherit the permissions.

After `sudo chgrp wheel /srv && sudo chmod g+ws /srv`, however, I still cannot create directories and files under `/srv`:

```
$ mkdir /srv/mantis
mkdir: cannot create directory `/srv/mantis': Permission denied
```

Examining the ACL on `/srv` shows that the effective group permission is only `r-x`, for some reason:

```
$ getfacl /srv
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: srv
# owner: root
# group: wheel
# flags: -s-
user::rwx
user:webmaster:rwx
group::r-x
mask::rwx
other::r-x
```

Any reason why this happens? Could it be that somehow when I added the additional access for the `webmaster` user (long before the `setgid` attempt) I accidentally tampered with the group ACL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a mask set by `setfacl` cause `chgrp` doesn't reflect the changes. You can run `setfacl -m g::rwx /srv` to set the group permission.

Otherwise, if you don't need advanced ACL at all, you can remove all rules by `setfacl -b /srvand` then re-run `sudo chmod g+ws /srv`.

*Before edit*

From the results of `getfacl` it seems that the command `sudo chmod g+ws /srv` was not working.  Seemingly you are running `sudo chgrp wheel /srv && sudo chmod g+ws /srv` as a single command.  If `sudo chgrp wheel /srv` failed (with a non-zero exit code for whatever reason), the `&&` connector  will simply ignore anything afterwards thus `sudo chmod g+ws /srv` will not be executed.

To illustrate, you can run `cat NoSuchFile && echo "This message will be printed"`. The `echo` command is ignored in this example.

You may try running `sudo chgrp wheel /srv` and `sudo chmod g+ws /srv` separately and note any messages.  Alternatively you may try `sudo chmod 2775 /srv` which should set the permission correctly.

Comment: `/srv` seems to already have the correct permissions and ownership though: `ls -ld /srv` yields `drwxrwsr-x+ 21 root wheel 4096 Feb 20 14:35 /srv`

Comment: Probably because you have a mask set by `setfacl` previously, so `chgrp` doesn't reflect the changes.  You can run `setfacl -m g::rwx /srv` to set the group permission.  Otherwise, if you don't need advanced ACL at all, you can remove all rules by `setfacl -b /srv`and then re-run `sudo chmod g+ws /srv`

Comment: Aha, that works. Not sure how the mask got affected, but thanks. Marking your answer as accepted -- could you merge the comment into it for future reference?